# Efficiently get first 10 results and total number of results

Tags: sql-server, c#

For a search page, I need the first 10 results and the total number of results of a query.

That part is easy:

```
SELECT TOP(10) ... FROM ... WHERE ... ORDER BY ...
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ... WHERE ...
```

But it's also amazingly slow. Both statements take about the same time.

So I found this one:

```
SELECT TOP(10) ... FROM ... WHERE ... ORDER BY ...
SELECT @@ROWCOUNT
```

That cuts down the time by ~50%. Great. But unfortunately the rowcount returned is 10. If I remove the "TOP(10)" the rowcount is correct, but the timespan is more or less the same as in the original version. (Even though I only access the first 10 rows.)

That's frustrating, because the total-number-of-lines info must exist, even in the TOP(10) version. (At least I think so, because we use a very complex ORDER BY clause, with 3 "CASE" conditions to sort empty data to the bottom)

Is there an efficient way to get both? TOP(10) data and total number?

Comment: `WITH cte AS (SELECT ...) SELECT TOP(10) *, COUNT(*) OVER () total_count FROM cte`. Then extract the count from any record and use another fields as a datasource. [example fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=f6124e403f44e97c03eee077f6e6af2d)

Comment: "the total-number-of-lines info must exist" -- wrong. The total number of rows is only known when the last row is retrieved. This is why `@@ROWCOUNT` is 10 after the query with `TOP(10)` -- only 10 rows are returned by the query, nobody knows how many more matching rows there might be.

Comment: If you have permissions to query sys.partitions, you can get the row count for your table by: select rows from sys.partitions where object_id = object_id(N'MyTable') and index_id = 1 (for clustered index) or 0 (for heap).

Comment: @QueueMann since it can only be either 0 or 1, you can say index_id IN (0,1). But you need to use SUM(rows) to account for partitioned tables.

Comment: https://sqlperformance.com/2014/10/t-sql-queries/bad-habits-count-the-hard-way

Comment: @AaronBertrand didn't account for that, but yeah - thanks.

Comment: @mustaccio: We have a complex ORDER BY condition. I doubt that it can be covered simply by clever use of the index. And if it's a real sort operation, then all the data should be there and the database should know the number. At least that's what I thought...

Comment: @Akina: Thanks for your comment, that seems to work, too and give similar performance. It's a bit weird to have the total number on each row, but it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your ORDER BY and WHERE clauses are complicated, then proposed solution should cut time in half:
1. Create a new table for intermittent results (it can be a temp table, table variable or memory optimized table with session id marker and schema_only setting).
2. Insert all rows from source query into this table, including order by expressions as additional columns.
3. Run your count and top 10 query from this new table.

Comment: Thanks, you're right, this greatly improves the performance.